# System.Diagnostic.Trace temp files

Tags: c#, logging

I'm using my own simple logger based on `System.Diagnostic.Trace`.

However in logs folder appear lots of temporally files with file name prefix like:
**"04157f3a-7f97-4514-a49d-e09e0e9f2248"**

Where those files are coming from?

How I can avoid that?

Comment: They are created when you attach to the debugger I believe.

Comment: Thanks for try Arran, but I check this on Release and the behavior is the same